# Shader in threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl, shader

I'm trying to use a shader in an application with `threejs`, but this [this](https://github.com/Ultimaker/Cura/blob/main/resources/shaders/grid.shader) particular `shader` doesn't work for me. When rendering, I do not see the objects on which it should be applied. Other simpler ones work well, but this one doesn't. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong. I took the `shader` from here. If anyone can help I would be extremely grateful

**shaders**

```
const vertexShader = `
    uniform highp mat4 u_modelMatrix;
    uniform highp mat4 u_viewMatrix;
    uniform highp mat4 u_projectionMatrix;

    attribute highp vec4 a_vertex;
    attribute lowp vec2 a_uvs;

    varying lowp vec2 v_uvs;

    void main()
    {
        gl_Position = u_projectionMatrix * u_viewMatrix * u_modelMatrix * a_vertex;
        v_uvs = a_uvs;
    }
  `;
  const fragmentShader = `
    #ifdef GL_ES
        #ifdef GL_FRAGMENT_PRECISION_HIGH
            precision highp float;
        #else
            precision mediump float;
        #endif // GL_FRAGMENT_PRECISION_HIGH
    #endif // GL_ES
    
    uniform lowp vec4 u_plateColor;
    uniform lowp vec4 u_gridColor0;
    uniform lowp vec4 u_gridColor1;

    varying lowp vec2 v_uvs;

    void main()
    {
        vec2 coord = v_uvs.xy;

        // Compute anti-aliased world-space minor grid lines
        vec2 minorGrid = abs(fract(coord - 0.5) - 0.5) / fwidth(coord);
        float minorLine = min(minorGrid.x, minorGrid.y);

        vec4 minorGridColor = mix(u_plateColor, u_gridColor1, 1.0 - min(minorLine, 1.0));

        // Compute anti-aliased world-space major grid lines
        vec2 majorGrid = abs(fract(coord / 10.0 - 0.5) - 0.5) / fwidth(coord / 10.0);
        float majorLine = min(majorGrid.x, majorGrid.y);

        gl_FragColor = mix(minorGridColor, u_gridColor0, 1.0 - min(majorLine, 1.0));
    }
  `;
```

**shaderMaterial**

```
const shader = new ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: {
      u_plateColor: { value: new Vector4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0) },
      u_gridColor0: { value: new Vector4(0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 1.0) },
      u_gridColor1: { value: new Vector4(0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1.0) },
    },
    vertexShader: vertexShader,
    fragmentShader: fragmentShader,
  });
shader.extensions.derivatives = true;
```

**functions**

```
function addPlane(scene: Scene) {
    const planeGeometry = new PlaneGeometry(200, 200, 10, 10);
    const plane = new Mesh(planeGeometry, shader);
    plane.receiveShadow = true;
    plane.quaternion.setFromEuler(new Euler(-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0));
    plane.layers.disable(1);
    scene.add(plane);
}

function addSphere(scene: Scene) {
    const sphere = new Mesh(new SphereGeometry(7, 32, 32), shader);
    sphere.position.set(10, 35, 15);
    scene.add(sphere);
}
```